# In Windows 10, is there a way to do a "reverse lookup" for a folder junction?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, junction

In other words, I know that someplace a junction exists that links to folder X - how can I find that junction? Or, since there could (theoretically) be more than one junction to this folder, how can I list them?
Alternatively, is it possible to search a folder for junctions based on where those junctions link to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view all the Symbolic links,Junction points,Hard links in a Folder using dir?](//superuser.com/q/823959)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a utility such as
[NTFSLinksView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html)
to list all junctions, then find your folder X in the column Target Path.
You may sort this column for easier search.

[image]